# Is $\mathbb Z$ a subgroup of a nontopologizable polybounded countable group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

A group $G$ is called

$\bullet$ *topologizable* if $G$ is algebraically isomorphic to a non-discrete Hausdorff topological group;

$\bullet$ *nontopologizable* if $G$ is not topologizable;

$\bullet$ *bounded* if $G=\{x\in G:x^n=1\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$;

$\bullet$ *polybounded* if $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{x\in G:f_i(x)=1\}$ for some semigroup polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_n$ on $G$.

A *semigroup polynomial* on a group $G$ is a function $f:G\to G$ of form $f(x)=a_0xa_1\cdots xa_n$ for some elements $a_0,\dots,a_n\in G$ with $n>0$.

**Example.** The semidirect product $G=\mathbb Z\rtimes \{-1,1\}$ endowed with the group operation $(x,i)*(y,j)=(x+iy,ij)$ is polybounded since $$G=\{x\in G:bxbx=e\}\cup\{x\in G:xx=e\}$$for the elements $e=(0,1)$ and $b=(0,-1)$.

**Remark 1.** By the Obraztsov Theorem, every (bounded) countable group without elements of order 2 is a subgroup of a countable group which is (bounded) simple and nontopologizable.
In particular the infinite cyclic group $\mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of a countable simple nontopologizable group.

> **Problem.** Is $\mathbb Z$ a subgroup of a nontopologizable polybounded countable group?

**Remark 2.** If a countable group $G$ is polybounded and nontopologizable, then $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{x\in G:f_i(x)=1\}$ and $\{1\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^m\{x\in G:g_i(x)\ne 1\}$ for some semigroup polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_n,g_1,\dots,g_m$ on $G$.

Comment: The group in your example is known as "infinite dihedral group" and often denoted $D_\infty$. Also, what you call "bounded" is often called, more explicitly "has bounded exponent".